# UICalendarView vs SwiftUI DatePicker wrong size in NavigationSplitView sidebar

Tags: swiftui, ipados, ios16, swiftui-navigationsplitview

Because i need to add badges to certain dates, i need to use a `UICalendarView` representable, however when using this in the `NavigationSplitView` sidebar, the width of the `UICalendarView` is incorrect... in contrast the graphical DatePicker which should be the same component, is layout correctly

In the detail pane the layout the same, the problem arises with less horizontal space

**How to fix this?**

[image]

```
struct CalendarUI: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let interval: DateInterval
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICalendarView {
        let view = UICalendarView()
        view.calendar = Calendar.current
        view.availableDateRange = interval
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UICalendarView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}

struct SidebarUI: View {
    
    @State private var date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CalendarUI(interval: DateInterval(start: .distantPast, end: .distantFuture))
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
            DatePicker(
                "Start Date",
                selection: $date,
                displayedComponents: [.date]
            )
            .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue as you: `UICalendarView` when wrapped in a `UIViewRepresentable` for use in SwiftUI is not resizing itself as expected and tries to take the full width.

The following solution works for me: In `func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICalendarView` add the lines below:

```swift
// Make sure our calendar view adapts nicely to size constraints.
view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

Further I have changed the `.fixedSize` modifier to not apply to the horizontal axis!

```swift
CalendarUI(interval: DateInterval(start: .distantPast, end: .distantFuture))
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```